# Is $\Bbb{R}$ with this metric $\rho(x,y)=\left| \frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|} \right|$ complete?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Is $\Bbb{R}$ with this metric $\rho(x,y)=\left| \frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|} \right|$ complete?

It is known that $$\rho(x,y)=\left| \frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|} \right|$$ is a metric on $\Bbb{R}$. However,  I'm thinking that $\Bbb{R}$ with this metric $\rho(x,y)$ is not complete but I can't think of an example. Anyone to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No!

Hint: Use the sequence  $x_n=(n)$

---

The sequence $x_n$ is Cauchy under $d$ is left as an exercise to you!

Suppose $x_n \to a$ under $d$. Then  $$0=\lim \Bigg\vert \frac{n}{1+n}-\frac{a}{1+\vert a \vert} \Bigg\vert= \Bigg \vert1-\frac{a}{1+\vert a \vert} \Bigg\vert$$ and the latter has no solution. Thus $x_n$ is not convergent under $d$!